# Transaction SERIALIZABLE, weird behaviour?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, serialization

I'm playing around with Transactions but I got a weird behaviour that I cannot explain. Maybe you could help me?

Consider 2 transactions, T1 and T2 both running under isolation level SERIALIZABLE.
T1 starts executing an insert without commiting.
T2 starts when T1 has executed its insert operation. However, T2 inserts 10k rows. But after 147 inserts, the error ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction.

However, this shouldnt happen, since T1 has no locks on this row ( Its not duplicate key or anything like that) So why does this even happen?

```
T1
INSERT INTO A 
VALUES(520089, 1, 'START', '198903111695', 'YEAR', 2017, '675013219393', 'I8', 'CREATED', '2016-08-09 18:26:49','2017-03-15 06:39:27');




T2
INSERT INTO A VALUES(520100,2, 'ACHIEVED', '196107246620', 'YEAR', 2018, '660564690379', 'I0', 'FULL', '2018-07-09 07:54:35', '2010-10-20 17:42:04');
INSERT A VALUES(520101,2, 'ACHIEVED', '196107246620', 'YEAR', 2018, '660564690379', 'I0', 'FULL', '2018-07-09 07:54:35', '2010-10-20 17:42:04');
.....for loop
INSERT INTO A VALUES(520147, 2, 'STARTED', '196503264535', 'MONTH', 201105, '305355347867', 'I8', 'TESTED', '2012-11-14 00:31:58', '2015-08-16 09:36:41')
here it crash, and gives me the error.
```

The only Primary key I have is the first value in A and the second value is a Foreign key.

So, can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: Look at this topic https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7636765105002

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using serializable transaction which will wait for other transaction locking the same table . Is it really needed. Just try remove the level.

Comment: serializable doesnt lock the whole table. You are wrong.